# about divisible abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G, H, K$ are divisible abelian groups , proof :

i)  if $G \oplus H \cong G \oplus K$ then $H \cong K$

ii) if $G \oplus G \cong K \oplus K$ then $G \cong K$

we know If $A$ is a divisible abelian group, and we let $\delta_{\infty}(A) = \dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(A/A_{\mathrm tor})$, and $\delta_p=\dim_{\mathbf{F}_p}(A[p])$, where $p$ is a prime and $A[p] = \{a\in A\mid pa = 0\}$, then two divisible groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if and only if $\delta_{\infty}(A)=\delta_{\infty}(B)$ and $\delta_p(A)=\delta_p(B)$ for all primes $p$.

Answer (score 3):

That’s wrong without further assumptions. Take $$G=\mathbb{Q}^{(\mathbb{N})}, H=\mathbb{Q}, K=\mathbb{Q}^2.$$

Comment: Your example addresses (i), but how about (ii)?

Answer (score 3):

(i) is false as @Mindiack stated. However, (ii) still holds.

We can easily check that $\delta_p(A\oplus A)=2\delta_p(A)$ for $p=\infty, 2,3,5,\cdots$. Hence $G\oplus G\cong K\oplus K$ implies $2\delta_p(G)=2\delta_p(K)$ for all $p$. If $\delta_p(G)$ is finite, then so is $\delta_p(K)$ and we gave $\delta_p(G)=\delta_p(K)$.

Otherwise, if $\delta_p(G)$ is infinite then so does $2\delta_p(G)$ and $2\delta_p(K)$. It is known that $2\kappa=\kappa$ for infinite cardinals $\kappa$, and thus $\delta_p(G)=\delta_p(K)$.
Therefore, $\delta_p(G)=\delta_p(K)$ for all $p$, which proves $G\cong K$.

Comment: why $\delta_p(A\oplus A)=2\delta_p(A)$ ?

Comment: @amirbahadory This follows from $(A\oplus A)/(A\oplus A)_{tor}\cong A/A_{tor} \oplus A/A_{tor}$ for $p=\infty$, and $(A\oplus A)[p] = A[p]\oplus A[p]$ otherwise.